# awk -F inside an alias command (tcsh)

Tags: linux, awk, alias, tcsh

I'm having some issues with aliasing the following command:

`a gl 'cat \!:1 | awk -F'-c ' '{print$2}' | awk -F' ' '{print($1)}'`

here's a sample of the text I am trying to parse - the goal is to reach the  after -c, the question is how to alias the awk command.

`command: cloud-tool -a <path to file> -b <path to file> -c <path to file> -d <path to file> -e <path to file> -f <path to file> param_alpha=on optimizeTriangle=on genericSupport=on forceConfig <path to file> pathConfig=/system/tool/configs/settings.txt SensorConfig: sensorMode=primary --synchronize=on --skipMissing`

grateful for any assistance!

Comment: You can't nest single quotes like that. The script should probably be refactored to `'awk -F "-c " "{ split(\$2, c, \" \"); print c[1]}" \!:1'` anyway. (I can't get the quoting completely right, but that is just another reason to abandon tcsh.)

Comment: can u please give an example, file, etc? It would be better to understand..

Comment: I expect you already know not to write scripts with [t]csh but just in case - https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not

Comment: @tripleee thanks, I get an Unmatched '"'. error with this.  I wish I could abandon tcsh but I can't

Comment: @ÖmerSezer here's the text in a sample file I want to parse, but with an alias command:  cloud-tool -a <path to file> -b <path to file> -c <path to file> -d <path to file> -e <path to file> -f <path to file> param_alpha=on optimizeTriangle=on genericSupport=on cityEntryMode=on forceConfig <path to file> pathConfig=/system/tool/configs/settings.txt SensorConfig: sensorMode=primary  --synchronize=on --skipMissing --replace

Comment: please update the question with these additional details; we shouldn't need to read through comments to get the complete picture; also, (possibly important) formatting is lost in comments

Comment: AND  add (to the body of your question) the expected output from that input. I'm surprised this isn't down-voted/close-voted yet, but I'll check back in 24 hrs from your original post to see if you have improved your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should achieve what you wanted :

```
alias gl 'awk -F"-c " '\''{print $2}'\'' \!:1 | awk -F" " '\''{print $1}'\'
```

The main idea is to put single quotes around awk-scripts.